# Select the last non-blank(visible) cell with a value in Column C

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice to VBA but well verse in writing formulas.

I would like a VBA code to go to Sheet "Slide 1 Chart 1", select the LAST CELL in Column C that has a populated(visible) cell value, copy that cell, and then paste(value only) into that same cell.

Each cell in Column C had/has a formula that pulls in "Values" if the formula is true. I run a report each day were the last cell with a value in Column C is dynamic by a formula. The cells above it are static(No formula). On the following day of running that report the last cell with a value needs to become static. Thus "Select", "Copy", "Paste(Values only)".

LastColumn;Row;Cell does not work as it still see's the formula in the visibly blank cell and considers it the lastrow. It should ignore the formulas and only look at if a value(not data) is populated.

Please help me with this!

Thank you,

[Last Cell with a visible cell value-formula in the cell][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJh5C.png

[Cells above "Last Cell with a visible cell value" formulas have been removed][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG8JU.png

[Cells below "Last Cell with a visible cell value" have formulas but no visible cell value. ][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnqlP.png

Comment: Not quite. But thank you. I need it to look at a cell in Column C and not the entire row.

Comment: Change the `ActiveSheet` to `Columns("C")`.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you're using, the formulas in that column, and how "that did not work." Please be specific.

Comment: I do not have a VBA code I'm using. I'm not sure where to start. However I have included screenshots of the "last cell in the column with a value", the cells above it showing no formula, and the cells below it showing a formula but no cell value. Also my request is to, select the last cell in a column with a value, copy that cell, and then paste the values back into the same cell. The link about did not satisfy all those requirements.

Comment: Please don't claim "that did not work" if you didn't try it. This isn't a code-writing site, and you most likely won't find a question that is literally an exact duplicate of yours... but there definitely are answers that show you the *approach* to take to fix yours.

Comment: We are not arguing semantics. I tried the code "in the link you sent me" even with "your" requested edits to it and it did nothing. Nor did it satisfy what I originally requested help for. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question then with exactly the code that you tried. Maybe you misunderstood my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            Set cell = r
        End If
    Next r

    cell.Value = cell.Value
End Sub
```